# Alias Select statement in JPA gives invalid column name

Tags: sql, jpa, glassfish-3

I have a problem with these aliased **"c"** select statements. I get a invalid column **"c"** error from the database. But all kinds of examples in the web use this type of writing the select statement.

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
"SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = 'Canada'");
Country c = (Country)query.getSingleResult();
```

Is this way of writing vendor specific?

Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say just c to get selected because it is just a alias name

You have to try something like this;

> select c.name
>    from country c
>   where  c.name='canada'

Answer (score 0):

When using a SELECT, you specify what columns from the database you want.
If you want all columns, use

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
```

or if you are joining tables, and only want columns from that table use

```
SELECT <table>.* FROM <table>
```

Comment: I found what's wrong. The above example is a query on the classes/entities and not a query on the native database. C represents the object instance. My mistake was that i mixed up native and normal queries.

Answer (score 0):

The above example is a query on the classes/entities and not a query on the native database. C represents the object instance. My mistake was that i mixed up native and normal queries.